# $this->security->get_csrf_hash() function is not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter custom form, I need to work with CSRF token, so i have used `$this->security->get_csrf_hash()`, but it is not working for me, can anyone please help mw how can i resolve this issue ? here is my code

```
<form role="form" data-parsley-validate="" novalidate="" class="mb-lg" action="?c=<?php echo isset($controller) ? $controller : "welcome"; ?>&m=login" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" type="email" placeholder="Enter email" autocomplete="off" required class="form-control">
                        <span class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback text-muted"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input name="password" id="exampleInputPassword1" type="password" placeholder="Password" required class="form-control">
                        <span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback text-muted"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="pull-right"><a href="?c=<?php echo isset($controller) ? $controller : "welcome"; ?>&m=resetpassword" class="text-muted">Forgot your password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php 
             $csrf = array(
                'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
                'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
                );
             echo "<pre>";
             print_r($csrf);
             die;
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $csrf['name'];?>" value="<?php echo $csrf['hash'];?>" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-lg">Login</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: did you enabled it in **application/config/config.php** like `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: @elddenmedio yes i did it

Comment: @elddenmedio its working now thanks

Comment: ok, only for log, what was the solution

Comment: I find in codeigniter CSRF works better when use a vhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in config file the following regeneration is true.

```
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
```

and in every post request pass the following name and value.

```
data:{get_csrf_token_name(): $this->security->get_csrf_hash()}
```